# TLS in golang http and grpc server

Tags: http, go, ssl, grpc, tls1.2

I've seen that some app developed in Go run without tls enabled from the app, rather enabled in its proxy server(nginx). The requests coming to the app is encrypted at the nginx side only. So the Go http server is served using only `http.ListenAndServe`.

While using gRPC, I've seen the gRPC server served without tls enabled, and the client dial with insecure mode enabled.

I assumed all of this because you only need enable tls only if you serve requests coming from outside(external networks). If you use http and grpc for internal services communication within internal network in microservices architecture, you don't need enable tls at all since it only adds overhead. Is this true?

How is tls properly applied in Golang development for http and gRPC server?

Comment: Whether or not you need tls for internal services depends on the situation. In cloud environment it usually makes sense to use tls internally as well. If tls is used internally, an internal PKI can be used to generate certificates, and traffic can be re-encrypted at the ingress. Other configurations are also possible.

Comment: This is entirely too vague. But in general: use TLS unless you have a really good reason not to. "overhead" is not a good reason.

Comment: https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-expensive-is-crypto-anyway/. I promise you that any "crypto overhead" is invisible compared to the actual work your service does. You should definitely enable TLS for reliable HTTP/2, and it should be end-to-end whenever possible.

Comment: So I need to enable tls at every end of my servers?. Let say I have a cluster of a service with 5 servers in it. These servers have nginx as proxy server and load balancer. So I have to put tls at nginx server and all those 5 servers as well?

Comment: First, even traffic within a cluster may be vulnerable to sniffing, depending on the network configuration. Do you have control of all network switches? In a cloud hosted environment, it's likely you do not. So if in doubt, encrypt internal traffic with TLS between cluster nodes. Second whether you terminate TLS at the service or at the proxy depends on how the proxy and the service communicate.